# Extracting images from a webpage under a specific tag

Tags: java, html, web, html-parsing, web-scraping

I want to know how to extract all images in a webpage under a specific tag. For example
if it is under:

```
<div class="img-style">
<img src="http://blah.../x.jpg">
```

I want to extract all the images under that specific div class using JAVA. Is it possible, any help would be appreciated

Comment: *"I want.."* ..a pony.  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: see above, what have you tried?

Comment: ok my framing of question wasnt right. Sorry. I have never dealt with HTML parsing, so I just wanted help to know how to do. Any examples would be sufficient :)

Comment: Server? Any particular framework? Libraries? What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to do this? Please post the full context of your problem.

Comment: I found example of extracting all links under img tag, but I wanted to know how to do of only img tags under a specific div tag

Comment: *"Any examples would be sufficient"*  But a link to an API (that probably has examples) is not enough to get you to the stage of asking a *specific* question? I would vote to close, if I'd not already done that!

Comment: @Gamb I want to use JAVA. Any library would do which works with JAVA. I need to extract all the images from a website under a specific tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love this library for scraping the internets http://jsoup.org/. I had a parser up and running in about 30 mins and have only been writing java in my spare time for 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

Here are other great HTML scrapping libraries for java: [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), [Web-Harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/). Using a library will make it much quicker and easier then starting from scratch with your own. Next time provide some methods you have tried/looked at too